# How to output 1x1 pixel from base64 using FOSRestBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony-2.6

I need to return this:

```
return header('Content-Type: image/png'); 
echo base64_decode('iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAQMAAAAl21bKAAAAA1BMVEUAAACnej3aAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAApJREFUCNdjYAAAAAIAAeIhvDMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
```

by using FOSRestBundle but I don't know how to handle the `echo` in there. I have this code:

```
public function getTrackingEmailAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher, Request $request)
{
    $view = View::create();
    $response = [];
    $view->setData($response)->setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png')->setStatusCode(200);

    return $view;
}
```

How do I send the base64 for display the `1x1` pixel? Do I need a view? (twig view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the upper code snippet, you don’t have to return Base64. Instead, the opposite is true: you have to return the raw image data, which is merely Base64-encoded as having binary stuff inside PHP code is not so nice ;-)

In your controller action, you therefore only have to return a proper Response with the image data as content

```
return new Response(base64_decode('...'), 200, ['Content-Type' => 'image/png']);
```